# Why is Manipulate breaking?

Tags: manipulate, piecewise

I am trying to `manipulate` a piecewise function. The first and second piece are attached at point x where x should also be manipulated (basically each curve has it's own stitching point).

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
a1 = MatrixForm[{0.55, 0.709, 0.709}, {0.24, 0.29, 0.709}];
b1 = MatrixForm[{0.97, 0.97, 0.97}, {0.61, 0.61, 0.97}];
a2 = MatrixForm[{0.55, 0.709, 0.0438}, {0.0072, 0.0087, 0.0438}];
b2 = MatrixForm[{0.97, 0.97, 2.}, {2.13, 2.13, 2.}];

dbhCrit = {96, 96, 26}; 
dbhAdult = {10., 10., 7.87}; 
size2bl[dbh_, ipft_, iallom_] := 
  If[dbh < 5, a1[[iallom, ipft]]*dbh^b1[[iallom, ipft]], 
       a2[[iallom, ipft]]*dbh^b2[[iallom, ipft]]];
pftColor = {Green, Red, Blue}; 
pftNames = {"Mid", "Late", "Lianas"}; 

Manipulate[
 Show[
  Plot[
   Evaluate@size2bl[dbh, ipft, iallom],
   {dbh, 0.0, 10.0},
   PlotStyle -> pftColor[[ipft]]
   ]
  ],
 Grid[{
   {Control[{{ipft, 1, Style["PFT"]},
      Table[i -> pftNames[[i]], {i, Length[pftNames]}], TogglerBar}], 
    Spacer[20],
    Control[{{iallom, 1, Style["IALLOM"]}, Range[2]}]}}
  ]
 ]
```

This `manipulate` works (though the colours are wrong) however what I should have is

```
If[dbh < dbhAdult[[ipft]], a1[[iallom, ipft]]*dbh^b1[[iallom, ipft]], 
           a2[[iallom, ipft]]*dbh^b2[[iallom, ipft]]];
    pftColor = {Green, Red, Blue};
```

If I use this last line the `manipulate` displays an empty graph.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the smaller example. You can see the problem if you watch the result of just `size2bl[dbh, ipft, iallom]` inside of `Manipulate` instead of the whole plot and select 'Lianas':

```
Manipulate[
  size2bl[dbh, ipft, iallom],
  Grid[{{Control[{{ipft, 1, Style["PFT"]},
         Table[i -> pftNames[[i]], {i, Npft}], TogglerBar}], Spacer[20],
         Control[{{iallom, 1, Style["IALLOM"]}, Range[Nallom]}]}}
  ]
]
```

[image: example]

You can see that the list structure propagated down into the piecewise function condition `dbh < {7.87}` and then stops. To achieve what we actually want we could either use `Thread` inside the piecewise function definition, but that would be a not very elegant way to solve it. Instead we should just make sure that `size2bl` only ever gets one combination of `ifpt` and `iallom` instead of whole lists and the problem will vanish. To do that we can just use `Table` to iterate over all combinations and `Flatten` to produce a one dimensional list instead of a matrix

```
Manipulate[
  Show[
    Plot[
      Evaluate@Flatten@Table[size2bl[dbh, i, j], {j, iallom}, {i, ipft}]
      ,{dbh, 0.0, 10.0}
      ,PlotStyle -> pftColor[[ipft]]
    ]
  ],
  Grid[{
    {Control[{{ipft, 1, Style["PFT"]}
    ,Table[i -> pftNames[[i]], {i, Npft}], TogglerBar}]
    ,Spacer[20]
    ,Control[{{iallom, 1, Style["IALLOM"]}, Range[Nallom]}]}}
  ]
]
```

[image: example2]

Comment: Hi Thies, thank you for taking the time to think about my issue. Your solution works although there is still a problem. It'a apparent from you image. While for `IALLOM=1` the curves are displayed properly, for `IALLOM=2` there are 2 curves for every colour. I guess that curves for both `IALLOM=1` and `IALLOM=2` are shown. Do you have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Ok I figured it out. Adding `TogglerBar` does the trick: [...] Range[Nallom],TogglerBar [...]